# How can I include multiple child tables with a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class Word
{
    public string WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key) (length: 20)
    public int WordIdentity { get; set; } // WordIdentity
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; } // WordForm.FK_WordFormWord
    public Word()
    {
        WordForms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<WordForm>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WordForm    {
    public string WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key) (length: 20)
    public int WordFormIdentity { get; set; } // WordFormIdentity
    public string WordId { get; set; } // WordId (length: 20)
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SampleSentence> SampleSentences { get; set; } // SampleSentence.FK_SampleSentenceWordForm
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordDefinition> WordDefinitions { get; set; } // WordDefinition.FK_WordDefinitionWordForm
    public WordForm()
    {
        SampleSentences = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SampleSentence>();
        WordDefinitions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<WordDefinition>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SampleSentence
{
    public int SampleSentenceId { get; set; } // SampleSentenceId (Primary key)
    public string WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (length: 20)
    public string Text { get; set; } // Text

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual WordForm WordForm { get; set; } // FK_SampleSentenceWordForm
}

public class WordDefinition
{
    public int WordDefinitionId { get; set; } // WordDefinitionId (Primary key)
    public string WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (length: 20)
    public string Text { get; set; } // Text (length: 50)
    public int? Ascii { get; set; } // Ascii

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual WordForm WordForm { get; set; } // FK_WordDefinitionWordForm
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve data for the word, wordForm, SampleSentences and WordDefinitions but I am not sure how to code the select. Here's what I have so far:

```
var words = db.Words
            .Include(w => w.WordForms)
            // How do I include SampleSentences
            // and WordDefinitions ?
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
```

Can someone tell me how I can also include SampleSentences and WordDefinitions? I tried to do this but it's failing syntax checks:

```
 .Include(w => w.WordForms.SampleSentences)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use select in your include:

```
 .Include(w => w.WordForms.Select(f => f.SampleSentences))
 .Include(w => w.WordForms.Select(f => f.WordDefinitions))
```

Comment: Thank you.  If I do this then do I still need to plain: .Include(w => w.WordForms) as well ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ no, because any Included path already includes all subpaths as well.